# Trying to do a simple post request in powershell v2.0, no luck

Tags: powershell

I'm simply trying to do a HTTP POST request with some keys and values. I can't get this to work for the life of me and yes I know this should be simple.

Here's what I've tried:

```
$Body = [byte[]][char[]]'username=asdf';
$Request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::CreateHttp('http://mysite/test.php');
$Request.Method = 'POST';
$Stream = $Request.GetRequestStream();
$Stream.Write($Body, 0, $Body.Length);
$Request.GetResponse();
```

This doesn't work in Powershell v2.0 because I get the error

> Method
>   invocation failed because [System.Net.HttpWebRequest] doesn't contain
>   a method named 'CreateHttp'.

Next, I've taken someone else's example of:

```
$URI1 = "http://mysite/test.php"

$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($URI1)
$request.ContentType = "application/xml"
$request.Method = "POST"
$body = "username=test"

# $request | Get-Member  for a list of methods and properties 

try
{
    $requestStream = $request.GetRequestStream()
    $streamWriter = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($requestStream)
    $streamWriter.Write($body)
}

finally
{
    if ($null -ne $streamWriter) { $streamWriter.Dispose() }
    if ($null -ne $requestStream) { $requestStream.Dispose() }
}

$res = $request.GetResponse()
```

but for some reason "username" doesn't get noticed when test.php echos $_POST['username']

Can someone please help tell me what I'm missing here? I've been googling for hours and everything I try isn't working for some reason. Works fine on Powershell versions greater than 2.0, but not 2.0 (default in Windows 7).

Invoke-WebRequest and Invoke-RestMethod do not work on Powershell v2.0, so I'm forced to find all these annoying alternatives.

*** EDIT ***

I got it working after finding another HTTP POST request example:

```
$url = "http://mysite/test.php"
$postData = "username=test"

$buffer = [text.encoding]::ascii.getbytes($postData)

[net.httpWebRequest] $req = [net.webRequest]::create($url)
$req.method = "POST"
$req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
$req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-US")
$req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate")
$req.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7")
$req.AllowAutoRedirect = $false
$req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
$req.ContentLength = $buffer.length
$req.TimeOut = 50000
$req.KeepAlive = $true
$req.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive: 300");
$reqst = $req.getRequestStream()
$reqst.write($buffer, 0, $buffer.length)
$reqst.flush()
$reqst.close()
[net.httpWebResponse] $res = $req.getResponse()
$resst = $res.getResponseStream()
$sr = new-object IO.StreamReader($resst)
$result = $sr.ReadToEnd()
$res.close()
```

This was discovered on another site before additional comments came here; however, I've tried the solutions from people's suggestions below and also was able to get this working.

Comment: A> `CreateHttp` isn't a method, it's `Create`; B> You set your content-type to XML, but your body is plain-text.

Comment: Thanks. I got it working now, finally! Sigh. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @LewlSauce, I'm happy you got it to work.  Please add an edit to your code and include the workign solution for others who find this post.

Comment: Done. Thanks @FoxDeploy

Answer (score 2):

In the first example code, the method should be named `Create`, Not `CreateHttp`

In the second block of code, you set the content-type to 'application/xml', but the body is plain-text.

Answer (score 1):

This method, and your initial example itself, would work in a newer version of PowerShell.  Try installing dotnet 4.5 on your system, then WMF 4.0, and this should work with no issue.

The dotnet class of `[System.Net.HttpWebRequest]` didn't have the static method `CreateHttp()` until dotnet 4.5, as [seen here on MSDN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382776(v=vs.110).aspx).

Why not just update this one machine to a newer version of PowerShell?  It will be a LOT less pain.

Comment: I was giving a script to a few individuals for some testing purposes and I can't have every single person install updates. Just wanted to find something that worked for older versions.

Trust me, I wish I could! :)

Comment: Today, Installing WMF 4 is not possible anymore since download is no more available